# Jquery Title drop down with other to be editable

Tags: jquery, html, field, title

I wan to select the tiles but able to edit the **other** and type what I want

I know I'm missing lots sorry...

http://jsfiddle.net/Rjqy5/57/

Title

Mr

Mrs

Miss

Ms

Other

Comment: oh, sorry. I want to be able to edit the "other"

Comment: selecting the tiles but able to edit the other

Comment: on selecting others. i will show some textbox in that he can enter some value like text then there should be an option for <a href="#">Test</a>. u r asking like this?

Comment: k.. on clicking mr what will happen?

Comment: if I click MR will be MR, only the other will change.

Comment: ThulasiRam did you try something out?

Comment: can u come on gmail chat? i need some calification...

Comment: @ThulasiRam I'm not sure how to get into chat really.

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/Rjqy5/70/ makes more sense, but dosn't work well and I don't want to use a plugin really.

Comment: I want to be able to edit only the Other. so as a salutation dropdown list, so the user can select Mr or Mss or Mrs, but in case wants to type "Engineer" the the world "title will change into "Engineer"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11011/discussion-between-dd77-and-thulasiram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown').live('mouseenter', function () {
                $('.sublinks').stop(false, true).hide();

                var submenu = $(this).parent().next();

                submenu.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 'px',
                    left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
                    zIndex: 1000
                });

                submenu.stop().slideDown(300);

                submenu.mouseleave(function () {
                    $(this).slideUp(300);

                    $('a#other').focus(function () {
                        $('#change').blur();
                    });
                });
            });

            $('#tbOthers').live('keypress focusout', function (e) {
                var textTitle = $.trim($(this).val());
                if (e.type === 'keypress') {
                    if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) === 13) {
                        if (textTitle.length === 0) {
                            $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="dropdown" id="change">Title</a>');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="dropdown" id="change">' + textTitle + '</a>');
                        }
                    }
                } else if (e.type === 'keypress') {
                    if (textTitle.length === 0) {
                        $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="dropdown" id="change">Title</a>');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="dropdown" id="change">' + textTitle + '</a>');
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#mainLink').find('.sublinks a').live('click', function (e) {
                var objChange = $('#mainLink').find('#change');
                if ($(this).attr('id') === 'other') {
                    objChange.parent().append($('<input />', { 'id': 'tbOthers', 'type': 'text' }));
                    objChange.remove();                   
                }
                else {
                    objChange.text($(this).text());
                }
            });

        });
```